# Button for adding boxes in grid-like manner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, grid

I want to make a button that would add views (box-like things) in such a manner that the 1st box would appear below the button, the 2nd to the 1st's right, the 3rd below 1st and so on, kinda like this:

```
[Button]
[1st][2nd]
[3rd][4th]
[5th] ...
```

I've got some code from some nice guy but while it does add the views they get stacked on top of each other and not in a manner I've shown above. Could someone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class teamCreateScreen extends Activity {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.team_locate_layout);
    }

    public void createTeam(View view) {
        final RelativeLayout rlTeam = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlTeam);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        if (tv.getId() > 0) {
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());
        }
        tv.setText("New Team");
        tv.setId(i);
        rlTeam.addView(tv, relativeParams);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also the XML layout in which the views are being added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rlTeam">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/teamAddBtn"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="createTeam"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Replace relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId()); with relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());

Comment: did it, nothing has changed :/

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to do this?

Comment: This is a part of an application I'm writing and im still kind of new to android. The button was meant to add those boxes that could later be modified (modifications later) in that good looking grid-like thing. If you're asking me this because you know how to achieve this in a different way please let me know, i would be grateful, still learning so anything helps.

Comment: Try to use *TableLayout* or *ListView*, maybe it will be easier for you.

Comment: I tried but that makes it even more complicated for me, all those ArrayAdapters and that kind of stuff just seems to make it even more confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are best thing to do this for example [Android GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Anyway try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private int counter = 0;
private int lastId = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void createTeam(View view) {
    final RelativeLayout rlTeam = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlTeam);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

        tv.setId(Utils.generateViewId());

    } else {

        tv.setId(View.generateViewId());

    }

    if(lastId == -1) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());
        counter++;
    } else if(counter == 1) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastId);
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, lastId);
        counter++;
    } else if(counter == 2) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);
        counter = 1;
    }


    tv.setText("New Team");

    lastId = tv.getId();

    rlTeam.addView(tv, relativeParams);
}
```

The Utils class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Created by Hema on 05/04/2015.
 */
public class Utils {
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in {@link #setId(int)}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    public static int generateViewId() {
        for (;;) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to show you why it was not working:
When you create view like this `Button tv = new Button(getApplicationContext());` if you call tv.getId() will equal -1 until you call tv.setId(int id).

Comment: You are welcome,  but you must to read about GridView and TableLayout

Comment: Woah, actually there's a little problem. When the views are being added they add below one another. Please take a look at the question, I've showed how they need to be added(grid). If possible, can you make some tweaking?

Comment: Thank you, I cannot stress just how much I needed this to work. You are awesome!

Comment: Code updated. But remember you must to read about GridView and TableLayoutyou.
Please tell me it is working as you want?

Comment: It's perfect, once again, thank you! I will definitely look into GridView and TableLayout, I have a lot to learn :)